# ls command to view particular string in filename within directory

Tags: ls

I have bunch of files in one directory. I want to list specific files within this directory whose name as follows;

```
stacov_abcd0230.15o
stacov_abcd0240.15o
stacov_ab120240.15o
stacov_01020240.15o
```

There are always 8 characters string after `stacov_` and `.[0-9][0-9]o` is the file format all the time.

The other files have also `stacov_` prefix but the lenght of the following strings are different than above file names like;

```
stacov_abcd_pre
result_stacov_abcd
```

How can I use `ls` command to view the relevant files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be absolutely precise:

```
ls stacov_????????.[0-9][0-9]o
```

in shell globbing `?` indicates any single character.

Answer (score 0):

The easier command for this is:

```
ls stacov_*.*o
```

But if the `*` after `.` are strictly numbers, then, you can use:

```
ls stacov_*.[0-9][0-9]o
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls stacov_[0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z][0-9a-z].[0-9][0-9]o
```